# Minimum iterations to guarantee a forward error of $\epsilon$

Tags: numerical-methods, roots, newton-raphson, standard-error

can anyone shed some light into this for me.

I am asked to numerically solve $$x\arctan(x) = 1$$ and to ensure that the error $\epsilon$ is less than $10^{-3}$. Now I usually use Newton's method for this and I have seen the following formula$$n \leq \frac{1}{\log(2)} \cdot \log \left( \frac{\log(\epsilon)}{\log(|p_0 - p|)}\right)$$
where $n$ is the number of iterations. It also says that $p_0$ is our initial guess and $p$ is the actual root. Now how would one go about this if they did not know the exact root? How can we use this formula?

Comment: There can't be a general formula like that that is independent of the equation under consideration. Also, what do you mean by error, do you mean any $x$ such that $x |\arctan x -1| \le {1 \over 10^3}$? Or do you mean the numerical solution is no more that $ {1 \over 10^3}$ away from a true solution?

Comment: I mean that $x \arctan (x) - 1 \leq  10^{-3}$

Comment: I don't think that $x \arctan (x) - 1 \leq  10^{-3}$ could be a convergence criteria.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you were looking for.

Let $f(x) = x \arctan x -1$, note that $f$ is even, $f(0) = -1$ and $f$ is increasing and unbounded on $x \ge 0$. In particular, a unique solution exists on $x \ge 0$.

Since you are only concerned about finding a point $x^*$ such that $|f(x^*)| < {1 \over 10^3}$, there is a particularly simple & fast strategy.

In the following I am assuming that $x \ge 0$ and $x^*$ is the unique solution.

Note that $f'(x) \ge 0$, $f''(x) >0$ (hence $f'$ is strictly increasing) and $f'(0) = 0$.
In particular, $f$ is convex.

Since $f$ is convex, if we start with any $x_0 >0$ (so that the iteration is defined) and use
Newton's method $x_{n_1} = x_n - {f(x_n) \over f'(x_n)}$, then $x_1 \ge x^*$ and
subsequently $x^* \le x_{n+1} \le x_n$.

In particular, as long as we start with $x_0 >0$, the iteration is well defined and
$x_n \to x^*$. Since $f'(x^*) >0$,
the convergence is quadratic.

So, just iterate until $f(x_n) < {1 \over 10^3}$.

If I pick $x_0 = 1$ then $x_1 \approx 1.670$, $x_2 \approx 1.623$ and $f(x_2) < 2 \times 10^{-12}$.

**More detail**:

A brief analysis shows that $|x_{n+1}-x^*| \le {1 \over 2} |{f''(\xi_n) \over f'(x_n)}| |x_n-x^*|^2$, where $\xi_n \in [x^*,x_{n+1}]$.

We can show that $f''(x_n) \in (0,1]$ for all $x$ and $f'(x_n) \ge f'(x_0) \ge 1$,
so we have
$|x_{n+1}-x^*| \le {1 \over 2} |x_n-x^*|^2$.

Since $f(1)<0$ and $f(2)>0$ we see that $|x_0-x^*| \le 1$ and a little work
shows that $|x_n-x^*| \le {1 \over 2}^{{1 \over 2} n (n+1)}$. Choosing $n=5$
gives $ {1 \over 2}^{{1 \over 2} n (n+1)} < {1 \over 10^4}$, so five iterations with exact numerics will guarantee that we are close to the solution and since
$f'(x) \le 2$ for $x \le 2$ we know that
$|f(x_5)| = |f(x_5)-f(x^*)| \le 2|x_5-x^*| \le 2 {1 \over 10^4}$ which is adequate.

Comment: @APMATH24: Glad to be able to help :-).